# Azure Event Hub Namespace is still getting resolved even its public access is disabled

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I was checking whether the public network access is blocked after disabling the public access to the Azure Event Hub Namespace from the portal. But still the namespace is getting resolved.

Updated the network settings in the portal as below,

[image]

But still the namespace is getting resolved when I tried,

```
nslookup <event-hubs-namespace-name>.servicebus.windows.net
```

Is this an expected behavior or what should we receive if it is restricted correctly?

Comment: Public network access settings are all IP or transport layer features. Changing the settings won't help to hide DNS records. Why are you concerned about the DNS still being public after disabling the public access?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca, agree with your point here. I noted that DNS entries can be retrieved using `nslookup` irrespective to network access configs. I could verify this by just hitting a curl request to my endpoint. Which serves **200 OK when public access is not restricted**, and serves **401 Unauthorized when public access is restricted**. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

> The public network access is blocked after disabling the public access to the Azure Event Hub Namespace from the portal. But still the namespace is getting resolved.

We can restrict/block access to specific Ip ranges by adding private endpoints within a virtual network.

[image]

*Traffic to a private-link resource is restricted when you use private endpoints. The platform verifies network connections and only permits the ones who successfully connect to the specified private-link resource*.

***Add a private endpoint***:

- Go to your `EventHub` from Azure portal.
- Path:

```
Networking -> Private endpoint connections -> Add a private endpoint within the same resource group and same virtual network.
```

- It enables access from the specified networks.

[Github for private end point creation](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/event-hubs-private-endpoint#connect-to-an-event-hubs-namespace-via-a-private-endpoint)

[image]

*After executing `nslookup` in  `Azure` cloud shell, received
endpoint details as shown below:*

[image]

**Note:** As mentioned in this  [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/troubleshooting-guide#what-ip-addresses-do-i-need-to-allow), nslookup will return the endpoint details in a non-authoritative answer for the Event Hubs but "***we can restrict the traffic to it from set of IPs/range and also include the Virtual Networks*"** as per our requirement.

Comment: My concern is not this. If I disabled all public access, why is it still getting resolved to me even there is no private endpoint configured. It is supposed to be blocked for all traffic, isn't it? I was thinking whether I need to add an private endpoint too with disabling public access to correctly disable all public traffic. If so, is there any official documentation that highlights this concern?

Comment: To restrict public access, we can create private end point or you can create a firewall to block traffic from specified range of IP’s. Does that meet your requirement?

Comment: As per your concern, Could you [check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-ip-filtering) this MsDoc?

Comment: I was looking to confirm that the endpoint is not accessible over the public networks access. I should rather use `curl` instead of `nslookup` as DNS entries will not be hidden from this config change. Thank you for your inputs!